# Can't find the gradle.properties file in the react native apk instructions

Tags: android, react-native

I'm following the instructions for a signed apk with react native https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.html

```
MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE=my-release-key.keystore
MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS=my-key-alias
MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD=*****
MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD=*****
```

However, in the step for setting up gradle variables, I can't find the `~/.gradle/gradle.properties` file on my mac.  I see a `~/.gradle` folder but I don't see the `gradle.properties` file there, should I create one?  Alternatively, I see a `/android/gradle.properties` file in my project folder - should I update the gradle variables there instead?

Also, should I replace the `MYAPP` keyword with my app's name?  If so, where do I find the key to replace that with - is that based on some sort of setting?  e.g. `FOOAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE` ...

Answer (score 2):

Go ahead and create one in your user folder `~/.gradle/gradle.properties`. Gradle can work with global (user variables) or with project ones.

The names of your variables doesn't matter either, but you have to remember to use them correctly when storing & reading values.

Also you have to create keystore for your app as described in [React Native - Generating Signed Apk](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.html)

Comment: I think by `~` you meant the home folder of the user (no relation with the project). Am i right?

Comment: @MohammedShareefC - yes, exactly. in unix systems `~` means user directory.